# Hibernate criteria from multiple independent tables

Tags: hibernate, criteria

In project I have multiple tables with same structure (numbers and types of columns). This tables are independent, I need hibernate criteria object that gives me all values from all tables. Something like in SQL:

```
 select * from TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3;
```

I know that I can merge results from multiple criterias in list etc. but I need one Criteria object because we are using it later in code in many places.

Answer (score 8):

You can use build criteria query from multiple roots, from the docs

> Roots define the basis from which all joins, paths and attributes are
>   available in the query. A root is always an entity type. Roots are
>   defined and added to the criteria by the overloaded from methods on
>   javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery

an addapted example from the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html#querycriteria-tuple)

```
CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery();
Root<Men> men = query.from( Men.class );
Root<Women> women = query.from( Women.class );
Predicate menRestriction = builder.and(
        builder.equal( men.get( Men_.gender ), Gender.MALE ),
        builder.equal( men.get( Men_.relationshipStatus ), RelationshipStatus.SINGLE )
);
Predicate womenRestriction = builder.and(
        builder.equal( women.get( Women_.gender ), Gender.FEMALE ),
        builder.equal( women.get( Women_.relationshipStatus ), RelationshipStatus.SINGLE )
);
query.where( builder.and( menRestriction, womenRestriction ) );
```

Comment: That's a good one but we are using older org.hibernate.Criteria API. No chance to do the same there?

Comment: Would it be possible to add even more roots? Those are resulting in cross joins and not returning expected results.